# tikzplotlib xticks not lining up with histogram as in the Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have code to draw a histogram in LaTeX.

```
plt.text(0.6*(ax.axes[0,0].get_xlim()[1]), 0.8*(ax.axes[0,0].get_ylim()[1]), r'$m=\${:0,.0f}$'.format(MostLikely(DataArray)))# Median
plt.xlim(left=0)
tikzplotlib.save(Filename, strict=True) #"${:0,.2f}".format(amt) r'$m=\${:.2e}$'
```

When this is plotted in Python, the x range is in [0 2.5]. however, the exported .tex file in LaTeX has a range of [-0,5 2.0]. I have tried several things to fix this, to no avail. Suggestions would be welcome.